# How to get the sheet name from Application.Caller?

Tags: excel, vba

It is possible to get the calling workbook name `Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent.Name` and cell address using `Application.Caller.Address`, for a function called in Excel.

Is there a way to get the sheet name, e.g. Sheet1, using `Application.Caller`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you pretty much had it already

```
Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name
```

Comment: Not working in VBA 7.0 not evening returning as a variable. The `caller` is a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim called_by As Variant
Dim x as string
Set called_by = Application.Caller
x = called_by.Parent.Application.Activesheet.Name
```

works fine in my application when calling this function within a cell.